# Type mismatch when trying to change the color of a line graph

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating three arrays with different color values.

```
Dim ColorR() As Variant
Dim ColorG() As Variant
Dim ColorB() As Variant

ColorR = Array(255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 128, 255, 0, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 255)
ColorG = Array(0, 0, 255, 128, 0, 255, 0, 128, 0, 128, 255, 64, 255, 0, 128, 128, 0, 0)
ColorB = Array(0, 255, 0, 0, 128, 255, 0, 128, 0, 255, 128, 0, 0, 255, 128, 0, 128, 255)
```

I then use them to change the color of each line in a line graph

```
For i = 1 to NumberOfLineGraphs
    mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor = RGB(ColorR(i), ColorG(i), ColorB(i))
Next i
```

But it says Type Mismatch. I have tried to change the arrays to Long, Double, Integer. Nothing works. Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe `.ForeColor.RGB` rather than just `.ForeColor` Perhaps `ForeColor` by itself was expecting a colorindex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're intending to colour the line using an RGB value, then you'd need to call the `RGB` property of the `Line.ForeColor` object. So, the code should be:

```
mychart.Chart.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(ColorR(i), ColorG(i), ColorB(i))
```